# Limits using layer-cake representations for $L^p$ space involving two functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Question: Let $f,g \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be such that $g \in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is measurable. If $\int_\mathbb{R} |f|^p |g| \, dx < \infty, 0 < p < \infty$ show that
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} t^p \int_{\{|f| > t\}} g\, dx = 0\ \text{and}\ \lim_{t \to 0^+} t^p \int_{\{|f| > t\}} g\, dx =0.$$

My attempt: Define $\mu(dx) = |g| \, dx$ then
$$\int_{\{|f| > t\}} g\, dx = \mu(\{|f| > t\}) = \mu(E_t)$$ where $E_t :=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \colon |f(x)|> t\}$. Since
\begin{align*}
+ \infty > \int_{\mathbb{R}} |f|^p \, d \mu &= p \int_0^{\infty} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt\\
&= p \int_0^1 t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt + p \int_1^\infty t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt\\
&= p \int_{\sqcup_{k\geq 0} F_k} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt + p \int_{\sqcup_{k\geq 0} B_k} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt
\end{align*}
where for each $k \geq 0$,
$$F_k :=\{2^{-(k+1)} \leq t < 2^{-k}\}, B_k :=\{ 2^k < t \leq 2^{k+1}\}$$
Using monotone convergence theorem, we have
$$+ \infty > p \sum_{k\geq 0} \int_{F_k} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt,\quad +\infty > p \sum_{k\geq 0}\int_{B_k} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt$$
So,
$$\lim_{k\to \infty}\int_{F_k} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt = \lim_{k\to \infty} \int_{B_k} t^{p-1} \mu(E_t)\, dt =0.$$ However, I am stuck at this step since I am not sure how to relate these two expression to the limit given in the question. Any hints/solutions are appreciated also can I check if $\mu$ is well-defined measure? As it is known that if $g$ is integrable $\mu$ is well-defined.

Comment: $\mu$ is a well define measure on $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and it is finite on compact sets since $g$ is locally integrable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu_f:=|g|\cdot dx$. Since $g\in L^{\operatorname{loc}}_1$, $\mu_g$ is a regular Borel measure (possible infinite) on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

For $t\rightarrow\infty$, the limit is rather straight forward if one uses Markov-Chebyshev's inequality:

$$t^p\int_{\{|f|>t\}}|g(x)|\,dx=t^p\mu_g(|f|>t)\leq\int_{\{|f|>t\}}|f|^p\,d\mu_g=\int_{\{|f|>t\}}|f|^p|g|\,dx\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow\infty}0$$
by dominated convergence. The result (for $t\rightarrow\infty$) follows from
$$\Big|t^p\int_{\{|f|>t\}}g(x)\,dx\Big|\leq t^p\int_{\{|f|>t\}}|g(x)|\,dx, \qquad t\geq0$$

---

For $t\rightarrow0$, the argument is a little more laborious.
Since $\mu_g$ is a regular Borel measure, the collection of $\mu_g$-integrable simple functions is dense in $L_p(\mu)$ for all $0<p<\infty$. Suppose $\phi=a\mathbb{1}_E$ with $\mu_g(E)<\infty$ and $a\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. As $\{|\phi|>t\}=E$ for $0<t<|a|$,
$$t^p\mu_g(|\phi|>t)\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow0+}0$$
For $\phi=\sum^m_{n=1}a_n\mathbb{1}_{E_n}$, where $\mu_g(E_n)<\infty$ for all $1\leq n\leq m$,
$$t^p\mu_g(|\phi|>t)\leq\sum^m_{n=1}t^p\mu_g(|a_n|\mathbb{1}_{E_n}>t/m)\xrightarrow{t\rightarrow0+}0$$

Here we use the fact that for functions $\phi_1,\ldots,\phi_m$ and numbers $b_1,\ldots, b_m$
$$\{\phi_1+\ldots+\phi_m > b_1+\ldots+ b_m\}\subset\bigcup^m_{j=1}\{\phi_j>b_j\}$$

Suppose that $\phi$ is a simple function such that $\|f-\phi\|^p_{L_p(\mu_g)}<\varepsilon$.

$$t^p\mu_g(|f-\phi|>t)\leq\int_{\{|f-\phi|>t\}}|f-\phi|^p\,d\mu_g\leq\|f-\phi\|^p_{L_p(\mu_g)}<\varepsilon$$

Then, from
$$t^p\mu_g(|f|>t)\leq t^p\mu_g\big(|f-\phi|>t/2\big)+ t^p\mu_g(|\phi|>t/2)$$
it follows that
$$\limsup_{t\rightarrow0+} t^p\mu_g(|f|>t)\leq2^p \varepsilon$$
and the conclusion for $t\rightarrow0+$ follows.

Comment: +1 and Corrected a typo. Retain it if its correct.

Comment: @Balajisb Thank you! Great solution. May I know how do u get the term $t/m$ for the estimation of $\phi = \sum_{n=1}^m a_n \chi_{E_n}$?

Comment: I did not answer the question. Its Mittens. but for your question, if sum of  $m$ numbers is greater than $t$ then atleast 1 number must be greater than the average $t/m$. Thats the Mittens  idea.

Comment: for nonngative functions $\phi$ and $\psi$, $\{\phi+\psi\leq a+b\}\supset \{\phi\leq a\}\cap\{\psi\leq b\}$. Then take complements.